# Grammar regarding the preposition "zu"

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Do we say

> Es kann eventuell die Tür zum anderer Projekte öffnen.

or rather

> Es kann eventuell die Tür zu anderer Projekte öffnen.

or are both wrong?
Please provide a grammatical clarification.

Comment: It would definitely be helpful to have not only the one sentence but also some context.

Comment: Since *kann* already indicates the optionality, *eventuell* is redundant.

Comment: @guidot I think the optional use of "eventuell" allows a more fine grained distinction about expressing the chance. If you add "eventuell" you can express more uncertainty about increasing the chance with other projects.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to translate: „to the projects of others“ or „to other projects“?!

Answer (score 7):

both are wrong.

**Projekte** is a neuter noun in German and it is plural. 
In that sentence it is dative.

**anderer** is male, singular AND it is nominative --> 3/3 wrong.

If you want to say "for ONE other project", then it would be:

> Es kann eventuell die Tür zum anderen Projekt öffnen.

If you want to say "for other projects", then the right answer is:

> Es kann eventuell die Tür zu anderen Projekten öffnen.

Comment: Grammatically, yes. But stilistically it is still a bit awkward. You would probably express it some other way, but for telling how we need more context.

Answer (score 3):

Both are wrong.

*zum* is an abbreviation for *zu dem*, which implies a singular object.

> Ich gehe zum Strand

The following would be wrong

> Ich gehe zum Fahrradständern

Also, *zu* requires the dative case, so the object must be in dative case:

> Es kann eventuell die Tür zu andere**n** Projekte**n** öffnen.

So you really have to decide what you want to say: Is it one project you're talking about? Then it would be

> Es kann eventuell die Tür zum/zu dem anderen Projekt öffnen

Or are you talking about the prospect of acquiring other projects? Then it would be

> Es kann eventuell die Tür zu anderen Projekten öffnen

Comment: There's a typo in your last line __Ee > Er_. Furthermore, it might sense to explain why the _Fahrradständern_ example is wrong or skip it entirely. At the moment, I can not see how it contributes to your message :)

Comment: Well, two lines above that I say "..., which implies a singular object". "Fahrradständern" is plural, that's why I'm giving the sentence as an example for "zum" being wrong here".